# Given huge list of sub sets, on receiving some super set find best match sub set

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, optimization

Given finder : List of map, key : String, Val  : String.

On receiving super map : a map which is super set of one or more map in a finder, find map from finder list which has contains maximum elements from super map.

For instance

```
Map { Name = Adam, Qualification = Engg, Job = Manager , Country =  US, City = Seattle}
```

list of sub maps :

```
   List [ submap1 {Name = Adam, Job = Manager }, 
      submap2 {Name = Adam, Country = Us, city - Seattle}
      submap3 {Name = Adam, Country = Us, city - Seattle, Job = 
        manager, Nickname = bobby} ] , size = 10000+
```

Result should be submap2. Is there a way I could utilize Tries/BST to pre-process list of subsets for faster look ups. Given that I have list of subsets at compile time and on receiving some uper set I need to find the best sub map. Any pointers would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to loop through the list of submaps. For each submap you count the number of matches. You keep the submab with the highest number of matches.

No need to use fancy data structures like tries unless you actually have to. (E.g. you have some specific performance issues.)

Comment: Number of sub maps is  >10k and dont want to iterate 10 k. I was thinking about proprocessing sulists and build indexes for items in map for faster lookups.

Comment: @sidss: You have to iterate through all submaps at least once reagardless of which solution you choose.